# In a table how to insert multiple records at a time in rails3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone tel me please how insert mulitple records in one table at a time. For example i have one table with three fields created and migrated so everything is fine. now while run it i will get index page with all records what i inserted into it.

Upto now I inserted in a normal way as single record inserted. Now i want to insert in the same table 10 rows at a time.

First I want to display 10 empty fields means in new page I want 10 empty rows and once field enter and submit then at a time have to insert in table.

Friends my question na.....

Please please tell me. Am trying this since 20 days but not getting..........

Comment: Does this model associated by has_many association in some other model?

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't have a particularly good way that I'm aware of to do bulk updates/inserts. Generally, you would use a loop that creates one item on each iteration. Assuming you have an array containing hashes with the desired attributes of your items, do something like:

```
item_array.each do |attributes| 
  Item.create(attributes) unless attributes.empty?
end
```

This is doing one database hit for each item. This is probably fine for 10 things, but would be problematic for larger numbers, in which case you might have to start writing your own SQL.